# One or more listeners failed to start. not getting deatiled error in any logs file

Tags: listener, failed-to-connect

[This is the error i am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsxeS.png)
I am trying to deploy one java based maven-web-application on tomcat i am able to deploy the application but it is not getting started and after checking related log files of tomcat server it says one or more listeners failed to start. as in above screenshot.

i tried checking all log files related to the application and also the related codes but not getting exactly how to get the error solved. soo i need the exact issue and ho to solve this.